# Pull Instagram Photos with a Specific Hashtag with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, instagram

I'm wondering how I can pull all photos with a hashtag on Instagram using Rails.

Answer (score -1):

Use [this endpoint](http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/tags/#get_tags_media_recent) in the instagram API, and parse the result.

If you want to actually download the photos, you'll need to write that part yourself, but is easy enough to do with Net::HTTP or HTTParty or whatever.